# How to combine regex, group them dynamically in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to form the regex using allowedPattern, MinLength, and  MaxLength properties from below JSON. I am using grouping and it working fine.

```
1) "DomainNetBIOSName" : {
  "Description" : "NetBIOS name of the domain (upto 15 characters) for users of earlier versions of Windows e.g. CORP",
  "Type" : "String",
  "MinLength" : "3",
  "MaxLength" : "15",
  "AllowedPattern" : "[a-zA-Z0-9]+"
},
```

From above json using minlength, maxlength and allowed patterns i'll form regex like this - ([a-zA-Z0-9]+){3,15}
It is working fine for the validation.

Now if i have json like this -

```
2)  "SourceCidrForRDP" : {
  "Description" : "IP Cidr from which you are likely to RDP into the instances. You can add rules later by modifying the created security groups e.g. 54.32.98.160/32",
  "Type" : "String",
  "MinLength" : "9",
  "MaxLength" : "18",
  "AllowedPattern" : "^([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+\/[0-9]+$"
}
```

Grouping of regex is not working for this example-

```
 From above json using same logic forming the regex like this - (^([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+\/[0-9]+$){9,18}$ which failing because of added length validation {9,18}.
```

I want to form a combined regex using minLength, maxLength and allowed pattern. Need a solution which will work fine for all the cases like this?

Answer (score 0):

The `{min, max}` does not represent a *minLength*, *maxLength* for the match. It says "match the previous token between *min* and *max* times".

It means that the first regex that seems to work (`([a-zA-Z0-9]+){3,15}`) does not work. It will match all alphanumeric sequence, even if it is longer than 15 characters.

What you want is this :
`^([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,15})$` (without the `+`). It will match a single alphanumeric character between 3 and 15 times and group the resulting sequence. It will not accept strings shorter than 3 characters and strings longer than 15 characters.

For your second regex, there is no need for a *minLength* and *maxLength*, the regex can force the string to represent an IP Cidr :

`^((?:\d{1,3}.){3}\d{1,3})\/(\d{1,2})$` ([regexr explaination](https://regexr.com/3psps))

This will retrieve the IP and separate it in two groups : `192.168.0.0` and `24` when given `192.168.0.0/24`.

So there is no need for a min and max length because the regex already forces the user to follow a pattern. You can drop the minLength and maxLength checks (or make it optional depending on whether your regex requires it or not).